# Replace top glass panels of a solarium

Tags: glass, sunroom

We have a solarium that is original to the house, 1970s. The top glass panels are fogged over, the double pane seal is broken. The side panels are fine. We are having difficulty finding a contractor to replace just the panels. We had a massive quote to replace the entire room, but I was wondering what my alternatives are as the rest of the structure is sound. We have a view of trees and we would prefer to keep them visible and not have opaque panels replacement.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: I'm not sure what type of answer you're expecting here. Unless one or more of your current set of contractors has explained good reason to not want to do the job, then either find someone who will make the double glazing units & replace them yourself, or keep looking for a contractor who is willing to do it.

Comment: Ask the reason for not doing just the roof.  Might be those panels are not available anymore and need to be made to order(very expensive), or he just wants more money.  Shaped or curved glass for an old design might not be made anymore, flat glass can be cut to fit almost anything.

Comment: Multi-pane windows are constructed of building blocks the glazing industry calls an "insulated glass unit." These can normally be custom-ordered bare, ie without the trimmings of a window frame etc. If you can share up-close photos of how the glass units are integrated into the solarium roof we may be able to advise as to how the fogged units could be removed and replaced.

Answer (score 1):

My friend has a large window that had its seal fail.

We drilled two tiny holes (1/8" or 3mm) in the window - top & bottom corner.

Then made a small pump and a dessicant filter to draw dry air through for a day or so.

Once clear we sealed it with bluetack (that sticky stuff to put pictures on walls without leaving holes. Been fine sine but we are ready to repeat.

Might be a cheaper option but do you want the messing around?

Comment: Would be time consuming for a roof amount of windows(I think).  Good idea though.

Comment: @crip659 The Op seems to be concerned primarily with the cost - maybe time is not such an issue...